# Select lines with a column value greather than another column value

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, having-clause

I'm trying to get the name of all authors that have more books than a specific author in my database.

Schema: (LIVRO means BOOK)

[image: Part of the Database Schema]

I have this query:

```
SELECT AUTORIA.CODAUTOR, AU.NOMEAUT, COUNT(AUTORIA.CODLIVRO) FROM AUTORIA
INNER JOIN AUTOR AS AU ON AU.CODIGO = AUTORIA.CODAUTOR
GROUP BY AUTORIA.CODAUTOR;
```

And that's what is returns:

```
+----------+------------------+-------------------------+
| CODAUTOR | NOMEAUT          | COUNT(AUTORIA.CODLIVRO) |
+----------+------------------+-------------------------+
|        1 | MACHADO DE ASSIS |                       7 |
|        2 | NAVATHE          |                       6 |
|        3 | ELMASRI          |                       7 |
+----------+------------------+-------------------------+
```

Now I need to filter this result with the lines that has the column COUNT(AUTORIA.CODLIVRO) with a value greather than the value of this column for the author NAVATHE.

That's what I tried:

```
SELECT AUTORIA.CODAUTOR, AU.NOMEAUT, COUNT(AUTORIA.CODLIVRO) FROM AUTORIA
INNER JOIN AUTOR AS AU ON AU.CODIGO = AUTORIA.CODAUTOR
GROUP BY AUTORIA.CODAUTOR /* Group books by author code */
/* Get authors with more books than NAVATHE */
HAVING COUNT(AUTORIA.CODLIVRO) > COUNT( /* Count how many books NAVATHE has */
    SELECT AUTORIA.CODLIVRO FROM AUTORIA /* Obtain the codes of the books of NAVATHE */
    INNER JOIN AUTOR AS AU ON AU.CODIGO = AUTORIA.CODAUTOR AND AU.NOMEAUT = 'NAVATHE'
);
```

But this query gives me an error.

Comment: Please don't paste text as screenshots.  Your SQL console should have been a text copy, not a screenshot .

Comment: Sure, I'll edit.

Comment: Thanks, it really does help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply remove the `COUNT()` around the subquery, and move it within the suubquery itself:

```
SELECT AUTORIA.CODAUTOR, AU.NOMEAUT, COUNT(AUTORIA.CODLIVRO) FROM AUTORIA
INNER JOIN AUTOR AS AU ON AU.CODIGO = AUTORIA.CODAUTOR
GROUP BY AUTORIA.CODAUTOR
/* Get authors with more books than NAVATHE */
HAVING COUNT(AUTORIA.CODLIVRO) > (
    SELECT COUNT(AUTORIA.CODLIVRO) FROM AUTORIA /* Obtain the codes of the books of NAVATHE */
    INNER JOIN AUTOR AS AU ON AU.CODIGO = AUTORIA.CODAUTOR AND AU.NOMEAUT = 'NAVATHE'
);
```

Comment: It worked ! Just put a parenthesis after the greater than sign: "> (".

Comment: I'm analyzing the other answer. But I'll probably accept yours when I understand properly the other. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 3):

Well, one way to get the id is:

```
SELECT a.CODAUTOR
FROM AUTORIA a
GROUP BY a.CODAUTOR
HAVING COUNT(*) > (SELECT COUNT(*)
                   FROM AUTORIA a2 JOIN
                        AUTOR au
                        ON au.CODIGO = a2.CODAUTOR
                   WHERE au.nome = 'NAVATHE'
                  );
```

I'll let you work out the `JOIN` (or `IN` or `EXISTS` clause) to get the author names.